# PyODBC - Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to Azure SQL using pyodbc. I tried a lot and failed to establish connection.
I installed the drivers using the below commands in macOS

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
brew update
HOMEBREW_ACCEPT_EULA=Y brew install msodbcsql18 mssql-tools18
```

Below is the code

```
import pyodbc

# Connection parameters
SERVER = 'mcp-mldb-prod-4fcf7c3f.database.windows.net'
DATABASE = 'mldb'
USERNAME = 'metauser'
PASSWORD = 'metapassword'
connectionString = f'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}};SERVER={SERVER};DATABASE={DATABASE};UID={USERNAME};PWD={PASSWORD}'
conn = pyodbc.connect(connectionString)
```

Below is the error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

## odbcinst -j

```
unixODBC 2.3.12
DRIVERS............: /opt/homebrew/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /opt/homebrew/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /opt/homebrew/etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/c0d032f/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

## File `/opt/homebrew/etc/odbcinst.ini`:

```
[ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/homebrew/lib/libmsodbcsql.18.dylib
UsageCount=1
```